# dyninamicly extendable form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Ok maybe I've overlooked something really simple here, but I can't seem to figure this out. I am trying to make my form dynamicly extendable.

My Problem is i can't get this code working:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $p = 1;
    $r = 1;
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
        function add()
        {

            document.getElementById("groesse").innerHTML = document.getElementById("grosse").innerHTML+"<input type='text' name='groesse[<?php echo $i;?>]'>";
            document.getElementById("preis_l").innerHTML = document.getElementById("preis_l").innerHTML+"<input type='text' name='preis_a[<?php echo $p;?>]'>";
            document.getElementById("preis_a").innerHTML = document.getElementById("preis_a").innerHTML+"<input type='text' name='preis_l [<?php echo $r;?>]'><br>";

            <?php
            $i = $i + 1;
            $p = $p + 1;
            $r = $r + 1;
            ?>
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    if ($_REQUEST['Selected'] == 'Speisekarte')
    {
        echo '<br><br><br><br>';
        echo '<input type="button" value="+" onClick="add()">';
        echo '<form action="insert.php" method="submit">';
        echo '<table border="1">';
        echo '<tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Beschreibung</td><td>Größe</td><td>Preis_L</td><td>Preis_A</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td><input type="text" id="ID" name="ID"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" id="Name" name="Name"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" id="Beschreibung" name="Beschreibung"></td>';
        echo '<td id="groesse"></td>';
        echo '<td id="preis_l"></td>';
        echo '<td id="preis_a"></td>';
        echo '</tr></table><input type="hidden" value="Speisekarte">';
        echo '<button type="submit">OK</button></form>';

    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want when someone klicks the `+`-Button my Form gets 3 Textfields more in the table with the specific ids. I also tried it with `div`-Tags but that didn't worked too.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use php clientside, it is parsed on the server only when visitor requests the page by GET or POST, so using $i = $i + 1 will not work clientside. By the way, use $i++ instead.

You could solve this with only javascript or, as an alternative, submit the form and present the form again with the extra fields needed so you can do it with php.

I recommend you have a look at jQuery and check out this answer with demo:
[How to use jQuery to add form elements dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744594/how-to-use-jquery-to-add-form-elements-dynamically)
(credits to PSL)

Comment: I have created my script base on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428103/how-to-add-dynamic-textbox-row-and-save-to-database-using-php)